# Match flags with countries in a multi.js input of shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets, multi.js

I have the dataframe below with the `multi.js` input with flags and countries. As you will see it is obvious that the countries do not match with glags displayed. How can I fix that?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
countries_df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lukes/ISO-3166-Countries-with-Regional-Codes/master/all/all.csv",strip.white = TRUE)
countries <- tolower(countries_df[,"alpha.2"])
countries2<-c("Afghanistan", "India", "Albania", "Bangladesh", "Sri Lanka", 
              "Belarus", "North Macedonia", "Serbia", "Ukraine", "Belize", 
              "Guatemala", "Bhutan", "Chile", "Mexico", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", 
              "Romania", "Slovenia", "Turkey", "Guyana", "Suriname", "Japan", 
              "Czechia", "Estonia", "Israel", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Slovakia", 
              "Algeria", "Canada", "Colombia", "Costa Rica", "Jordan", "New Zealand", 
              "Peru", "Barbados", "Dominica", "Grenada", "Jamaica", "Montserrat", 
              "Bahamas", "Cuba", "Dominican Republic", "Haiti", "Cameroon", 
              "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Gabon", "El Salvador", "Honduras", 
              "Nicaragua", "Panama", "Hungary", "Poland", "China", "Egypt", 
              "Ghana", "Guinea", "Mali", "Morocco", "Tunisia", "Ecuador", "Pakistan", 
              "Singapore", "Kazakhstan", "Angola", "Burundi", "Comoros", "Djibouti", 
              "Eritrea", "Eswatini", "Ethiopia", "Kenya", "Lesotho", "Madagascar", 
              "Malawi", "Mauritius", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Rwanda", "Sudan", 
              "Uganda", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe", "Armenia", "Azerbaijan", "Georgia", 
              "Kyrgyzstan", "Tajikistan", "Turkmenistan", "Uzbekistan", "Benin", 
              "Botswana", "Burkina Faso", "Cook Islands", "Equatorial Guinea", 
              "Fiji", "Gambia", "Guinea-Bissau", "Kiribati", "Liberia", "Marshall Islands", 
              "Mauritania", "Micronesia (Federated States of)", "Nauru", "Niger", 
              "Nigeria", "Niue", "Palau", "Papua New Guinea", "Samoa", "Senegal", 
              "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Solomon Islands", "South Africa", 
              "Togo", "Tonga", "Tuvalu", "Vanuatu", "Cyprus", "Denmark", "Ireland", 
              "Andorra", "Iraq", "Indonesia", "Malaysia", "Belgium", "France", "Germany", "Italy", "Luxembourg", "Netherlands", "Libya", "Somalia", 
              "Western Sahara", "Faroe Islands", "Greece", "Austria", "Finland", 
              "Sweden", "Lebanon", "Malta", "Montenegro", "Portugal", "San Marino", 
              "Spain", "Liechtenstein", "Bahrain", "Kuwait", "Oman", "Qatar", 
              "Saudi Arabia", "United Arab Emirates", "Philippines", "Thailand", 
              "Nepal", "Australia", "Cambodia", "Maldives", "Mongolia")
img_urls <- paste0(
  'https://cdn.rawgit.com/lipis/flag-icon-css/master/flags/4x3/',
  countries, '.svg'
)

input_widget <- multiInput(
  inputId = "Id010",
  label = "Countries :", 
  choices = NULL,
  selected = countries2[1],
  choiceNames = lapply(
    seq_along(countries2), 
    function(i) {
      tagList(
        tags$img(src = img_urls[i], width = 20, height = 15), 
        countries2[i]
      )
    }
  ),
  choiceValues = countries2
)
ui <- fluidPage(
  input_widget
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making use of separate vectors of country names and codes you could filter your `country_df` dataset for your desired `countries2`. Then replace all occurrences of `countries` and `countries2` in your shiny code by the `name` and `alpha.2` columns of `country_df`. Doing so makes sure that each code gets assigned to the right name:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

countries_df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lukes/ISO-3166-Countries-with-Regional-Codes/master/all/all.csv", strip.white = TRUE)
countries_df <- countries_df[c("name", "alpha.2")]
countries_df$alpha.2 <- tolower(countries_df$alpha.2)

countries_df <- countries_df[countries_df$name %in% countries2, ]

img_urls <- paste0(
  "https://cdn.rawgit.com/lipis/flag-icon-css/master/flags/4x3/",
  countries_df$alpha.2, ".svg"
)

input_widget <- multiInput(
  inputId = "Id010",
  label = "Countries :",
  choices = NULL,
  selected = countries_df$name[1],
  choiceNames = lapply(
    seq_along(countries_df$alpha.2),
    function(i) {
      tagList(
        tags$img(src = img_urls[i], width = 20, height = 15),
        countries_df$name[i]
      )
    }
  ),
  choiceValues = countries_df$name
)
ui <- fluidPage(
  input_widget
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73099597/update-a-dataset-after-putting-a-new-value-in-the-dtdatatable could you take a look at this?